# How to add validation in Material ui form input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, material-ui

I have a react functional component built using Material ui form which contains `TextField` and `onChange` event is handled in "Container Component". Below is the form code where i need to add `required` as client side form validation but, its not working. Do i need to add some logic in container component as well?

```
<form className={classes.container}>
<Grid container item xs={12} alignItems="center">
<TextField
  id="outlined-bare"
  className={classes.textField1}
  defaultValue=""
  required
  margin="normal"
  variant="outlined"
  autoComplete="on"
  InputProps={{ style: { height: 40 } }}
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'Name')}
/>
```

and here is event handler in container component like below

```
 setInput = (e, source) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch  (source) {
        case "Name":
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                Name: e.target.value
            })
            break;
    default:
            this.setState({...this.state})
            break;
    }
}

 return (
        <div>
            <Drawer
                route={routes.abc}
                history={this.props.history}
                handleChange={this.setInput}
            />
        </div>
    )
```

What's wrong, and is missing? I am new to ReactJs. Kindly suggest.

Comment: What is your submit function? That is where I would put client side validation, but I don't see one.

Comment: @BrianThompson I have a `Submit` function which will read the value entered in TextField and call redux action. I need validation to be handled before it..Thanks

Comment: @BrianThompson Do you think, its possible or shall i put condition to check `TextField` value inside submit function? In this case, where is `required` working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With what information is available, I would suggest doing something like the following simplified version:

Container

```
class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      other_value: '',
    }
  }

  handleChange = (field, value) => {
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
  }

  valid = () => {
    if (!this.state.name) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  submit = () => {
    if (this.valid()) {
      // call your redux submit
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyForm
        values={this.state}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        submit={this.submit}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Form component

```
const MyForm = (props) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.submit}>
      <TextField
        onChange={(e) => props.handleChange('name', e.target.value)}
        value={props.values.name}
        required
      />
      <TextField
        onChange={(e) => props.handleChange('other_value', e.target.value)}
        value={props.values.other_value}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

First, if you are using an `onChange` on your input, you should also provide its value to insure they remain in-sync.

Second, If you want the `required` prop to have an effect, you should make sure your submit function is called by the form. The `required` prop is just passed down to the `input` element which will get used by the wrapping `form` [(explanation of required)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp). So if the form isn't the one calling your submit function, `required` will be ignored.

Lastly, I only provided a simple validate function, if you want it to be more comprehensive, just add more checks and return specific errors or an array of errors instead of a simple true or false. You could also skip the validation function completely if a simple required check is all you need.